# How do I edit the spacing between categories on the x-axis using ggpplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart in ggplot where the data for each of three regions is contained in separate dataframes. I am adding three geom_bars to the plot and using position_nudge to adjust the spacing between the bars, which has worked for some charts but not for this one due to it having many categories.

```
EduPlot <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = EduEDLessT, aes(x = Highest.Level.of.Education.Completed2, y = PercentageOfPopulation, fill = "Electoral Division"), width= 0.4, 
           position = position_nudge(0.3), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = EduStateLessT, aes(x =  Highest.Level.of.Education.Completed2, y = PercentageOfPopulation, fill = "Republic of Ireland"), width= 0.4,
           position = position_nudge(0), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = EduACLessT, aes(x =  Highest.Level.of.Education.Completed2, y = PercentageOfPopulation, fill = "Local Authority"), width= 0.4,
           position = position_nudge(-0.3), stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Highest Level Of Education Completed")+
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, margin = margin(t = 0.5, unit = "in")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0)),
        legend.position = c(0.125, 0.9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "% of Population Aged 15+")
```

The best I could get from using different values for position_nudge is contained in the attached image. It looks to me like my solution would be to edit the distance between the categories on the x axis so that I can make position nudge wider without overlapping bars from different categories. Can someone help me here please?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is this using RMarkdown and Knit to PDF or something like this?

Comment: Why not `cbind` the data sets with an 'origin' column or similar and use the origin as a grouping variable?  I suspect this would be simpler.

Comment: Agree with Paul. The easiest approach would be to bind your data into one using e.g. `list("Electoral Division" = EduEDLessT, "Republic of Ireland" = EduStateLessT, ...) %>% bind_rows(.id = "category")`. Then only one `geom_bar` is needed and you could simply use `aes(.., fill = category)` with `position = "dodge"`.